# Beware of Greeks bearing gifts

Tags: proverbs

I am looking for an English equivalent for a proverb of my language which says: "A wolf (a bad person) will never laugh at you, but it wants to get something (an achievment) from you".

I have found a similar saying in English, but I have my doubts if native speakers use it;

> - **Beware of greeks bearing gifts**. (With reference to the story of "Trojan horse".)

Please help me to find its English Equivalent.

Comment: In today's world, a usage with a particular nation/ race/ ethnicity may invoke people getting offended by it. So, it's better if you restrain from using proverbs and phrases like this.

Comment: You're right @Vaurun Nair. That was one of the reasons behind raising this question. :)

Comment: Try using "Beware of a wolf in sheep's clothing" instead. You are unlikely to upset wolves or sheep.

Comment: @davo Aside from some offensive aspects, my own sentence is not considered as a common saying in English at all?

Comment: I have never, until now, heard your saying with the wolf. I have many times (but less frequently of late) heard the one about gifts.